# Word for an intense look

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word for an intense look to replace "gaze" in the following context.

> I look at Adaneene with resignation; I shouldn't have expected anything different, but instead of looking at me with blood-lust, she's looking into the woods around us.
>
> She bares her teeth, clenches her hands, looks in four distinct directions. She's seen our backup.
>
> Her *gaze* returns to Mac and I.

Now, I did use a reverse dictionary and thesaurus (http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml?s=Intense%20look) ; typed in "intense look" and a ton of words came up. The only words that were semi-applicable were the top three, "stare, gaze, and glare."

But, *stare* is not the right word because this character is not staring, she merely looking, or perhaps "observing keenly" or "noticing" would better describe what she is doing. But, I need a noun, and "keen observation" and "notice" would not fit at all.

Gaze is not the connotation I'm looking for.

Glare implies anger, which is not the case here.

So, is there a word I can use which would fit into this context?

Comment: If you check a thesaurus for, eg, "stare" you will get a bunch of suggestions.

Comment: *Gaze* actually seems to work IMO. You say that it doesn't have the right connotations, but why? Many definitions actually use the descriptor *intent*. You could always use *keen gaze* over *keen observation*. Or even something like *aggravated* or *antagonistic gaze* depending on context.

Comment: @silenus I can see what you mean, but it just doesn't seem right. When I think of gaze I think of star-gazing or gazing at the moon, not gazing at people that could potentially be prey.

Comment: Well, if it helps convince you, here are some examples of *malicious gaze*: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22intent%20gaze%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl#lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22malicious+gaze%22. Plug in other adjectives as you see fit.

Comment: How 'bout ***attention***?

Comment: For a less passive meaning, how about "scrutiny?"

Comment: Focus.  Her focus returned to us. This gives a sense that she was very interested in us but does not have a negative connotation.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that her *focus* returns.

> a : a center of activity, attraction, or attention
>   <sub>*definition from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/focus)*</sub>

(and it would be "to Mac and me", not "to Mac and I"; you and Mac are the object, and thus any pronoun there should be in the objective case.)

Answer (score 0):

> 1 ogle : verb \ ˈō-gəl also ˈä- \
>
> to look at especially with greedy or interested attention.

This is the closest I can get to your request. Hope it helps

[Source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ogle)

Comment: Please edit your post according to [these directions on how to reference material that you do not own](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Also consider that we expect answers to consist mostly of your own words, not merely other people's words copied in. Unattributed material may be deleted or challenged.

Answer (score 0):

A) 
1. **Gawk** "stare openly and stupidly."
2. They all stopped to **gawk** at the artwork done by a little girl; a masterwork that rendered a powerful Phoenix bird.

Comment: It doesn't really fit into the sentence in the question though.